# Mongodb replicaset secondaries showing not reachable/healthy and lastHeartbeatMessage shows No connection could be made

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

Mongodb replicaset secondaries showing not reachable/healthy. It was working fine once the machine restarted it shows both secondary as reachable/healthy. I configured first secondary in the port 27027 and second secondary in 27037. When i Checked rs.status() i got below result.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:52:50.311Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(5),
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 1,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 1,
    "votingMembersCount" : 1,
    "writableVotingMembersCount" : 1,
    "optimes" : {
            "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1616478761, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(5)
            },
            "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:52:41.265Z"),
            "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1616478761, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(5)
            },
            "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:52:41.265Z"),
            "appliedOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1616478761, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(5)
            },
            "durableOpTime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1616478761, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(5)
            },
            "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:52:41.265Z"),
            "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:52:41.265Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1616478711, 1),
    "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
            "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
            "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:44:09.131Z"),
            "electionTerm" : NumberLong(5),
            "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                    "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1616478202, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(4)
            },
            "numVotesNeeded" : 1,
            "priorityAtElection" : 1,
            "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
            "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
            "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:44:11.152Z"),
            "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:44:11.238Z")
    },
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "name" : "127.0.0.1:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 540,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1616478761, 1),
                            "t" : NumberLong(5)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:52:41Z"),
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1616478249, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:44:09Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 3,
                    "configTerm" : 5,
                    "self" : true,
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "127.0.0.1:27027",
                    "health" : 0,
                    "state" : 8,
                    "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                    "uptime" : 0,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:52:47.779Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27027 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "configVersion" : -1,
                    "configTerm" : -1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "127.0.0.1:27037",
                    "health" : 0,
                    "state" : 8,
                    "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                    "uptime" : 0,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-03-23T05:52:47.768Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27037 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "configVersion" : -1,
                    "configTerm" : -1
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1616478761, 1),
            "signature" : {
                    "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                    "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
            }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1616478761, 1)
}
```

Comment: **Suggestion**: try to avoid pasting unnecessary info with your post.
As per the status (_not reachable/healthy_) probably the `mongod` service is down on that node, you have to restart the service.

Comment: I assume the secondary mongod services are simply not started.